# Can someone explain what's happening with the HTTP status?

Tags: cookies, python-requests, http-status-code-404

I get a 404 error while checking the link using requests library for the page below while the page opens fine in the browser when I reach to it from it's parent [page](http://www.dell.com/en-us/work/learn/internet-of-things-solutions). Can someone please help me understand what's happening?. I get the same error using [this](http://404checker.com/404-checker) service as well.

```
url = "http://www.dell.com/en-us/learn/assets/shared-content~data-sheets~en/documents~2016-v5-systems-oem-10022706.pdf"
response = requests.get(url)
print response.status_code
```

Comment: I get a 404 on that link, also in Firefox.

Comment: Yes. Can you please try opening http://www.dell.com/en-us/work/learn/internet-of-things-solutions first and then http://www.dell.com/en-us/learn/assets/shared-content~data-sheets~en/documents~2016-v5-systems-oem-10022706.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first URL sets a cookie, that is sent to the server as you request the second link. If you call the second link with exactly the same request, excluding the cookie, you get a 404.

Comment: thank you. Why doesn't this happen with other PDFs? And what if a visitor accesses the PDF directly maybe from a google search result?

Comment: This is just how that part of the Dell site is built. It happens because it was written that way. Other parts of the site might be differently structured or built. If the site was built well, the direct-link from Google might be another link, or it won't even show up at all.